# Android CCS GCM registration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to GCM and CCS. I have setup GCM using PHP by referring [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

Now I am trying to jump from HTTP to CCS but I am not able to register CCS.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnGCMRegister;
    Button btnXmppRegiser;
    Button btnSendMessage;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    Context context;
    String regId;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> sendTask;
    AtomicInteger ccsMsgId = new AtomicInteger();

    static final String GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "306923*****";
    public static final String REG_ID = "regId";
    private static String APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

    static final String TAG = "Register Activity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        APP_VERSION = getAppVersion(context)+"";
        btnGCMRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGCMRegister);
        btnGCMRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
                    regId = registerGCM();
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "GCM RegId: " + regId);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Already Registered with GCM Server!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        btnXmppRegiser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnXmppRegiser);
        btnXmppRegiser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId is empty!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    sendMessage("REGISTER");
                }
            }
        });

        btnSendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage);
        btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId is empty!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    sendMessage("ECHO");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(final String action) {

        sendTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putString("ACTION", action);
                data.putString("CLIENT_MESSAGE", "Hello GCM CCS XMPP!");
                String id = Integer.toString(ccsMsgId.incrementAndGet());

                try {
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "messageid: " + id);
                    gcm.send(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id,
                            data);
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "After gcm.send successful.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Exception: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "Sent message.";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                sendTask = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        };
        sendTask.execute(null, null, null);

    }

    public String registerGCM() {

        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regId = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {

            registerInBackground();

            Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                    "registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId: "
                            + regId);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "RegId already available. RegId: " + regId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return regId;
    }

    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                    "I never expected this! Going down, going down!" + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regId = gcm.register(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                            + regId);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

                    storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
                }
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you try to use the `gcm.register` method which is a deprecated. Trying to use the `InstenceId`, and you can find the sample code [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/399e88c1ef5bb95395b6392f9061e45b2fb5d49a/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/InstanceIdHelper.java). Check out `getTokenInBackground`.

Comment: @bjiang i tried this but its not working..

Comment: You can try whole sample here:https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/399e88c1ef5bb95395b6392f9061e45b2fb5d49a/samples/android/gcm-demo

Comment: @bjiang i tried a lot buts not working plz plz help me i tried 2 days p;z help me friend i badly need this gcm and css

Comment: Why it not working? can you give me some details or any error in logcat?

Comment: @bjiang sorry for this i am unable to update every time can u plz tell me some place where i can share my whole source code with you

Comment: you can zip your project folder, upload to the google drive and share the link with me

Comment: ok i will thanks by evening i will upload

Comment: and if u dont mind then can u give me skype orfacebook id or teamviewer id where i can discuss on project plz i badly need help

Comment: @bjiang please help me i really need help ican give my gcm api and sender id plz help me bjiang